# exception in for loop?

Tags: c, exception

Why my code returns:

> Exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x10d637fa2)

in the first time it enters the for loops?

```
void unAnnoyWord(char *str) {
    char *out = str, mostAnnoying = 'a';
    do
    {
        if (*str != mostAnnoying)
        {
            *out = *str;
        }
    } while (*str++);
}

char *str = "hakuna matata";
unAnnoyWord(str);
```

Comment: C may allow `char *str = "hakuna matata"`, but that can be considered a language defect. Pointers to string literals should always be declared const qualified. Turn on your compiler warnings. Most will tell you it's dangerous to do what you did.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void unAnnoyWord(char *str) {
    char *out = str, mostAnnoying = 'a';
    do {
        if (*str != mostAnnoying) {
            *out++ = *str;
        }
    } while (*str++);
}

void main() {
  char str[] = "hakuna matata";
  char *sstr = str;
  printf("%s\n",sstr);
  unAnnoyWord(str);
  printf("%s\n",sstr);
}
```

Resulting in:

```
hakuna matata
hkun mtt
```